# Productive plants in shade

Tags: sunlight, shade, hot-weather

I live in the desert with temperature seasonal extremes of about 0°c - 45°c (or freezing to really hot) and over 300 days of sun annually.

On the north side of my back yard I have a cinder block wall running parallel to an east-west street.  Along this wall I have a very nice lemon tree that casts shade on a ~10 square foot patch of dirt that is over-sprayed with water from my sprinkler system.  This patch of dirt might receive as much as an hour of light as the sun sets.

Are there any food producing plants I can plant that will do well in a continuously wet but almost completly shaded area?